# How to process several files with one script?

Tags: node.js, nuance

Hello I am using Nuance to make some experiments about speech to text for this I am using node to create the request as follows:

My credentials:

```
var Nuance = require("nuance");
var nuance = new Nuance("mycredentials", "mypass");
```

Then I send the request as follows:

```
nuance.sendDictationRequest({
    "identifier": "randomIdentifierStringHere", //The user identifier (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "language": "es_MX", //The language code (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "path": "12min.amr", //The path to the file you would like to send to Nuance.
    "additionalHeaders": {}, //If you'd like to supply more headers or replace the default headers, supply them here.
    "success": function(resp){ //The success callback function.
        console.log(resp);
    },
    "error": function(resp){ //The error callback function - returns the response from Nuance that you can debug.
        console.log("An error was occurred.");
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

The problem for this way is that I need to use several calls changing this part:

```
"path": "12min.amr", //The path to the file you would like to send to Nuance.
```

Since I execute the request in terminal as follows:

```
node call12.js
```

And then I get the result on the terminal.

I tried:

```
nuance.sendDictationRequest({
    "identifier": "randomIdentifierStringHere", //The user identifier (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "language": "es_MX", //The language code (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "path": "4min.amr", //The path to the file you would like to send to Nuance.
    "additionalHeaders": {}, //If you'd like to supply more headers or replace the default headers, supply them here.
    "success": function(resp){ //The success callback function.
        console.log(resp);
    },
    "error": function(resp){ //The error callback function - returns the response from Nuance that you can debug.
        console.log("An error was occurred.");
        console.log(resp);
    }
});


nuance.sendDictationRequest({
    "identifier": "randomIdentifierStringHere", //The user identifier (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "language": "es_MX", //The language code (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
    "path": "2min.amr ", //The path to the file you would like to send to Nuance.
    "additionalHeaders": {}, //If you'd like to supply more headers or replace the default headers, supply them here.
    "success": function(resp){ //The success callback function.
        console.log(resp);
    },
    "error": function(resp){ //The error callback function - returns the response from Nuance that you can debug.
        console.log("An error was occurred.");
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

to process only 2 conversations I am repeating code since I don't believe that this is the optimal way.
In order to process all of my files:

```
2min.amr 4min.amr 8min.amr
```

I would like to know how to create a for in order to process more files in one script, so I really would like to appreciate support to overcome this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
var fileNames = ['2min.amr', '4min.amr', '8min.amr'];

fileNames.forEach((item) => {
    nuance.sendDictationRequest({
        "identifier": "randomIdentifierStringHere", //The user identifier (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
        "language": "es_MX", //The language code (please refer to Nuance's documentation for more info).
        "path": item, //The path to the file you would like to send to Nuance.
        "additionalHeaders": {}, //If you'd like to supply more headers or replace the default headers, supply them here.
        "success": function(resp){ //The success callback function.
            fs.writeFile("my_text.txt", resp, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('The file has been saved!');
            });
        },
        "error": function(resp){ //The error callback function - returns the response from Nuance that you can debug.
            console.log("An error was occurred.");
            console.log(resp);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: @neo33, use `fs` built-in module of node.js to work with file system. Here is the `fs.writeFile(fileName, data, callback)` function you need to pass your response into.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: @neo33, check it

Comment: @neo33, oh, sorry, my fault. Edited in a wrong way. But you got the idea! Good luck!

Comment: No worry I got very well the idea thanks for the support